# TypeError: gulp.registry is not a function

Tags: gulp

I'm running just basic gulp file and keep getting this error

```
TypeError: gulp.registry is not a function
```

Gulp file looks like:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const HubRegistry = require('gulp-hub');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

const conf = require('./conf/gulp.conf');

// Load some files into the registry
const hub = new HubRegistry([conf.path.tasks('*.js')]);

// Tell gulp to use the tasks just loaded
gulp.registry(hub); // fails here
```

Node version is v6.2.1 got this also on v6.5.0 npm version v3.9.3.

Problem persists on Mac and on Windows 10. Tried several things like deinstalling, removing gulp, etc..but can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using **gulp 4**.Make sure you have to install **npm install gulpjs/gulp#4.0**

Comment: yup gulp4 is solution, tnx!

Comment: When I tried this error. Error while executing C:\Users\ravi\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git

Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

exited with error code: 128

Comment: **npm i gulp@next** is now the correct command to install Gulp 4.0.0

Comment: Gulp 4 comes with its own set of issues, the solution to which could conversely be to move back to v3. This creates a cyclic response. It would be more informative to address this issue within the context of v3.